# Unable to pass variable from codeigniter controller to the view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined, scope

At the moment I have a controller which should send a variable holding an array to my view but this currently is not happening.

There is no actual data/rows within this mySQL table and I don't know if that may be the reason that it shows the following error: `Message: Undefined variable: jobs` in views/applicantjobs.php

controller: applicantjobs.php

```
$employer_jobs = $this->db->get_where('jobs', array('employer_profile_id' => $user['id'] ));
$jobs = $employer_jobs->result_array();

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('applicantjobs', $jobs);
```

view: applicantjobs.php

```
foreach($applicantjobs as $applicantjob){
    echo $applicantjob['name'];
}
```

Any help is really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `Message: Undefined variable: jobs in views/applicantjobs.php` while `$jobs` is used only in the controller (as far as I know)? Are you sure those are the lines the error comes from?

Comment: Please mark error line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data['jobs'] = $this->db->get_where('jobs', array('employer_profile_id' => $user['id'] ))->result_array();

$this->load->view('applicantjobs', $data);
```

Try this one

And in your view:

```
foreach($jobs as $job)
{
   echo $job['name'];
}
```